# How to plot a sine curve for longer time duration

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to Python and **trying to plot a sine curve for a time duration of 300 seconds** on the x-axis but I am only able to plot a correct sine curve for a short duration.

**MWE:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

in_array = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 300)
out_array = np.sin(in_array)

print("in_array : ", in_array)
print("\nout_array : ", out_array)

# red for numpy.sin()
plt.plot(in_array, out_array, color = 'red')
plt.title("numpy.sin()")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

The code above is able to plot the desired sine curve as shown below:

[image]

If I change the `np.linspace` line in the above code to

```
in_array = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, 300)
```

...then I am able to get the 3 cycles of a sine curve, which is also okay.

[image]

**Problem:** If I try to plot the sine-curve for 300 seconds (approx.) on the x-axis by using `in_array = np.linspace(0, 90*np.pi, 300)` in the above code then the curve contains **different amplitudes** (as shown below), why and how can I correct it?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In all the cases you've mentioned you have the same number of x-axis points generated.

When the interval is shorter with 300 points you get more dense representation of `sin`, i.e. there're enough points around each local maxima / minima to plot the extremes correctly. In the first example you have 1 x-axis point per 0.02 radian.

In the last example you still got 300 points, but wider interval. That means that you roughly have 1 point per 0.95 radian and sometimes the points don't land around the extremes, therefore they are not plotted, therefore visibly different amplitudes.

You can add more points to x-axis (make them more frequent).

For example, 900 points look good again:

```
in_array = np.linspace(0, 90*np.pi, 900)
out_array = np.sin(in_array)

plt.plot(in_array, out_array, color = 'red')
plt.title("numpy.sin()")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case, we knew the expected curve and could immediately recognize that the curve is not plotted correctly (because of the less number of points). But imagine plotting an UNKNOWN curve. Is there any rule of thumb or a trick in Python which can be used for the correct sampling? (nyquist frequency?)

Comment: @skm You wrote _"Is there any rule of thumb or a trick in Python which can be used for the correct sampling?"_ — well, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76895268/2749397) is exactly focused in establishing the maximum sampling step needed to contain the error in the extremes values of a trig function.

Comment: @gboffi: Yes, I read your answer and also tried to write a generic program out of it (posted as an answer with results). I am wondering if the Nyquist Sampling rate can be used as a way to decide on the step size but the step-size computed using Nyquist Sampling rate are coming out to be bigger than the one you described in your answer.

Comment: @skm Please forget the Nyquist frequency, your problem is a different one.

Comment: @gboffi: Could you please provide a hint why the Nyquist Sampling rate theorem is not applicable here? I tried to write a generic program based on the `delta-t <= (5w)-1` formula you suggested but the program does not work for lower frequency (e.g. f = 0.02 HZ).

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that you're plotting your sin *ωt* with a fixed time step Δ*t*,
and *t*<sub>n</sub> is the sample point closest to a maximum of the sine function, then you have the maximum error when *t*<sub>max</sub> - *t*<sub>n</sub> = Δ*t*/2, and the maximum error is (Taylor series, neglecting fourth order terms)
                                 *ε*<sub>max</sub> = (*ω*Δ*t*/2)<sup>2</sup>/2.
If you want to limit the maximum error, e.g., to 0.005 you can write *ε*<sub>max</sub> = (*ω*Δ*t*/2)<sup>2</sup>/2 ≤ 1/200,
and solving for  Δ*t* you finally have *Δ*t ≤ (5*w*)<sup>-1</sup>.
In general, with *ε* the maximum *relative* error that is admissible, you have
                                 Δ*t* ≤ (8*ε*)<sup>1/2</sup>/*ω*.
The determination of the maximum time step required to limit the *absolute* error is left as an exercise.

---

It may be interesting to write
                                 *ω*Δ*t* = (8*ε*)<sup>1/2</sup>
because the number of points in a cycle, *N*, is given by
                                 N = 2π / *ω*Δ*t* = 2π / (8*ε*)<sup>1/2</sup>
so that, solving for *ε* we have
                                 *ε* = π² / 2n²
and eventually  we can draw the following chart, that confirms the rule of thumb "use 10 points per cycle to limit the error to a max of 5%".
[image]

---

As a check

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ω = 1
t = np.linspace(0, 0.2, 1001)

plt.figure(layout='constrained')
plt.plot(t, np.cos(ω*t), lw=0.5, color='k')
for ε in (0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02):
    Δt = np.sqrt(8*ε)/ω
    plt.scatter(
        Δt/2, np.cos(ω*Δt/2),
        label=r'$ε=%0.3f, ω\,Δt=%0.3f$'%(ε, Δt))
plt.xlabel('$ωt$')
plt.ylabel('$\\cos ωt$')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

[image]

---

**[The below comment from the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76894594/how-to-plot-a-sine-curve-for-longer-time-duration/76895268#comment135564205_76895268)** left me with the doubt that I was missing something, so I wrote and checked (5') this code.

Judging from the figure the code produces, there are no issues with undersampling, but of course I may be wrong.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = 0.02
w = 2*355/113*f

max_err = 0.005
w_dt = pow(8*mx_err, 1/2)
dt = w_dt/w

t0, t1 = 0, 300
t = np.linspace(t0, t1, int((t1-t0)/dt))
plt.plot(t, np.sin(w*t))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I wrote a program based on the formula you described. For frequency = 2, it worked fine but if I tried the program at a lower frequency (let's say `f = 0.02`), again got the same under the sampling problem.

Comment: @skm  I have posted some code to plot *y* = sin(2π·0.01 *t*) for 0 ≤ *t* ≤ 300s. Is it possible that my previous explanations are confusing?