# Plotting Sine curve using Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am facing a problem in writing a **generic program** that can automatically adjust the number of points required **to plot a sine curve** if the frequency and the total duration for the plot are given.

Based on the suggestions provided by [Maria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76894669/2386113) and [gboffi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76895268/2386113) on another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76894594/how-to-plot-a-sine-curve-for-longer-time-duration/76894669?noredirect=1#comment135569994_76894669), I have written the following generic code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# Take formula delta-t <= 1/(5*omega) from SO answer "https://stackoverflow.com/a/76895268/2386113"
frequency = 0.02 #Two HZ
delta_t = math.floor( 1/(5*2*np.pi*frequency))

total_duration = 300
num_points = math.ceil(total_duration/delta_t)
t = np.linspace(0, total_duration, num_points)
sine_t = np.sin(t)

#Only for test: to plot a line of constant amplitude
straight_line = t/t

# red for numpy.sin()
plt.plot(t, sine_t, color = 'red')
plt.plot(t, straight_line, color = 'blue')
plt.title("numpy.sin()")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

**Problem:** The above code works fine for `frequency = 2 Hz` but if I set the `frequency = 0.02 Hz` then I again get a wrong plot (which can be corrected by increasing the number of points hard-coded). How can I generically compute the number of points based on the frequency and the duration?

**At frequency = 2 Hz (Correct)**

[image]

**At frequency = 0.02 Hz (Wrong)**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Based on [chrslg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20037042/chrslg) suggestion in the comment (which makes sense), I corrected the code and used `np.sin(t*2*np.pi*frequency)`. The updated part of the code is (note that frequency is set to 2 now):

```
frequency = 2 #Two HZ
delta_t = max(math.floor( 1/(5*2*np.pi*frequency)), 1)

total_duration = 300
num_points = math.ceil(total_duration/delta_t)
t = np.linspace(0, total_duration, num_points)
sine_t = np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency*t) #sin(omega * t)
```

As a result of the above code, I am getting the sine-curve below which is again **wrong** because `frequency = 2` means that there should be 2 sine waves per second and hence 600 sine waves for a duration of 300 seconds, which is not the case in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: But you are not plotting a sine at this frequency. You are plotting a sin at frequency 1/2π. Are you sure you are not supposed to plot `np.sin(t*2*np.pi*frequency)`?

Comment: @chrslg: You are right but even with the correction, I am not getting the correct number of sine waves. Please have a look at my update above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take twice as many samples as the frequency in Hz. This is a result of the Nyquist sampling theorem ( More information [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/nyquist-shannon-theorem-understanding-sampled-systems/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem#:%7E:text=The%20sampling%20theorem%20was%20implied,and%20reconstruction%20of%20continuous%20signals.) ). In simple terms, if the periodic function has a frequency `f` in `Hz`, and you want to reconstruct the periodic wave fully, you will need at least `2f` points **per second** to do so. And it happens that the sine function is a periodic function.

If you have the frequency in Hz you can use the following code snippet (a slight modification of your original code):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

frequency_hz = 1

total_duration = 4
multiplicator = 40  # nyquist recommends to samples at least 2*frequency in Hz per second
num_points = math.floor(total_duration * frequency_hz * multiplicator) + 1
print(num_points)
t = np.linspace(0, total_duration, num_points)
sine_t = np.sin(t * 2 * np.pi * frequency_hz)

# Only for test: to plot a line of constant amplitude
straight_line = t / t

# red for numpy.sin()
plt.plot(t, sine_t, color="red")
plt.plot(t, straight_line, color="blue")
plt.title("numpy.sin()")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

That generates this plot:
[image: sine wave]

I recommend changing `multiplicator` to a large number such as `20` to always have a clear plot.

I used the floor function so that `num_points` is an integer. The `+1` `num_points` is not really necessary.

I'm not sure in what unit 0.02 is, but I think this code can be adapted to that unit too!

Comment: (1) Per the question, 0.02 is in Hz. (2) You set the frequency to 15Hz, yet you don't plot the sine wave with that frequency.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I edited the response to fix the issues mentioned in both of your points

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why that 5ωT number of points was suggested (T being the total duration).
It makes partly sense, because it is proportional to the number of periods to be drawn. So if 5ωT is ok for one value of ω, it should be ok for any other values. It means that each full period, whatever the number of them in whatever interval, is drawn by 31.416 points.

That is more than enough indeed, to see the sine. But still, that `.416` means that each period is not drawn at the same relative abscissa. It means, more importantly to you, if I get correctly what you want, that the highest point in each period is not always the same (sometimes, it end up almost exactly at `sin(π/2)=1`. But then, the next period peak is represented by `sin(π/2+2π31/31.416)` and `sin(π/2+2π32/31.416)`.

The usage of `floor` in the `delta_T` computation partly solves that problem, ensuring that in ends up in an integer number of point per period anyway (and therefore, each period has the same sampling, however bad or good, and therefore that the whole sine looks with a constant amplitude)

But also, that `floor` is what poses your problem right now. Because, for any frequency big enough (over 0.031, which doesn't sound so big), that `delta_t` would round to 0. I guess that is why you added that `max(...,1)`, which prevents the division by 0 error, but not the problem: your `delta_t` is a very rough approximation.

If you want to have a constant number of sampling per period, then, just do that.

```
K=8 # K=4 is the strict minimum to see 0, 1, 0, -1, repeating
# K=a factor of 4 is needed if you want two of the samples to be 1 and -1, that is to see the whole amplitude

num_points = math.ceil(K*frequency*total_duration)
# either frequency*total_duration is an integer (that is there is an 
# exact number of periods in the interval, which was the case in both of
# your examples. 300×0.02 = 6 complete periods. 300×2 = 600 of them)
# and then, floor is useless (except for typing reasons)
# or it isn't, and then, just using `math.ceil` doesn't solve the problem: 
# it isn't the correct sampling: we need to also adjust total_duration, so 
# that an exact number of kth of period is represented by `num_points`
total_duration = num_points/K/frequency

# Another important point: you need `num_points` from 0 included to
# total_duraction excluded. Or else you don't distributed evenly your points
# (total_duration is the 1st point of the next period, not the last of this one)
# Or, if you really need to include `total_duration` abscissa, then,
# you need `num_points+1` not `num_points` points
t = np.linspace(0, total_duration, num_points, False) # False meaning "excluded"
# or
t = np.linspace(0, total_duration, num_points+1, True) # True, meaning included, is the default, I explicit it here to show the difference

sine = np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency*t)
plt.plot(t, sine)
plt.show()
```

Minimalistic `K=4, frequency=0.02` result
[image]

K=12, freqency=0.02. Since K is a factor of 4, we still see the full -1,1 amplitude, with more points

[image]

K=5, frequency=0.02. Since K is not a factor of 4, sampling at highest point is not exactly at π/2 phase, that is we don't have a full -1,1 amplitude. But at least, it is always the same, since there are exactly 5 points per period.
[image]

K=32, frequency=0.02. That is quite close to 2×5π you seem to have got from another answer. But at least it is exact. And a multiple of 4.
[image]

K=32, frequency=0.017. Since with this frequency this isn't an exact number of periods (not even of 1/32th of periods) in the (0,300) interval, we adjust that interval so that we still have an exact number of samples per period (so we really draws from 0 to 301.47 here, to be able to still have a repeating pattern of K=32 samples per period)

[image]